Scheduling Classification in OR research area
I am currently working on a paper where I have a physician scheduling problem. Apart from physician schedules, we also have another resource besides their treatment that can plan to diagnose and care for the patients. These are nursing robots that do not have the same effectiveness as nurses but can still perform tasks for them. Now I'm finding it difficult to narrow down the literature. In which area can I find similar concepts/literature?

Scheduling with resource constraints?

Conventional OR techniques could be an option, but you may also want to look at AI scheduling literature, as then tend to focus more on general purpose problems (les structure). Take a look at proceedings at ICAPS conference for some papers to help you get started, and the works of Prof. Stephen Smith (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=fCFwERYAAAAJ&hl=en) on applications of task planning and scheduling using Simple Temporal Networks.

@Tim B, would you elaborate more on what exactly you are looking for? And also explain more about what actually the robots do besides the nurses?

A distinction that typically matters classification wise:
Is it task scheduling or shift scheduling? The difference: shift scheduling happens weeks before and impacts the employees's social life. Can they attend their sister's birthday party? Task scheduling happens hours before and is confined into the shift hours. It doesn't affect the employees social life (except if it creates overtime).
